# For each loop not working in Batch file

Tags: batch-file, tortoisesvn

I'm very new to Batch scripting so please consider that.

I'm trying to make an automated update of all SVN project folders when i log into windows.

The issue is in the for loop. I want to iterate over all path variables but it seems not to work.

Here is the code.

```
@echo off

set svnPath="C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe"
set numPaths=3

set path1=C:\projects
set path2=E:\projects\ConnectsProjects
set path3=E:\projects\CSLibs

set /P ANSWER=Would you like to synchronize with SVN? (y/n)

if /I {%ANSWER%}=={y} (
    echo --- Synchronizing with SVN repository ---

    for /L %%i in (1,1,3) do (
        %svnPath% update !path%%i!
        echo --- Updated path !path%%i! ---
    )

    echo --- Finished ---
    sleep 2
)
```

The problem is that the svn update command takes the parameter `!path%%i!` literally.

I found the syntax for this in a few google results, so it should be right shouldn't it?

Thanks for the help.

Greetings Johny

Comment: You need `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`. It is not in the shown code. Did you miss it?

Comment: @Stephan  Make it an answer and Johny can accept it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
`setlocal enabledelayedexansion`.
```

Looking at the use of delayed variables in your `if`-block, I think you are aware of delayed expansion. So you just forgot that line.

for other "searchers": best put it quite after `@echo off`